# How to do the Hindu meditation for enlightenment and samadhi?

Tags: meditation

I was reading Raja Yoga from swami Vivekananda , does it have the correct process for meditation.

I have heard that Hindu meditation for third eye and stuff.

Comment: Read 8 limbs of Yoga from Patanjali's Yoga Sutras...

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange! Visit some related questions on [mediation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/519/277) and about [Raja Yoga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9043/277)

Comment: @YDS Swami Vivekananda's Raja Yoga book is already having in it Yoga Sutras with Swamiji's commentary.

Comment: @Rickross yes, but in case user wants to check the original text and not the translation...

Comment: @YDS I have the Raja Yoga book. It has original Sanskrit texts of all the sutras, Swamiji's translations and commentary.

Comment: @Rickross Did I deny that fact? Shall I delete my comment if u don't like...I just gave the another reference as user has mentioned that he/she is already reading RajaYoga from Swami Vivekananda...

Comment: Haha no.. what i mean is if someone is reading Swamiji's Raja Yoga then he is already reading Patanjali's Yoga Sutras. No need to buy it or read it separately. @YDS

Comment: Please post your main question in the body also. Currently, tour title and body are not asking the same questions.

Comment: Your question asking if it is the correct method or not makes your question opinion based and opinion based questions are not allowed.